# Функция для очистки динамической памяти C++

Tags: c++

Написал функцию, которая очищает динамическую память. Проблема в том, что как только программа завершает выполнение функции, памяти возвращается прежнее значение. Не понимаю, как это работает.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void CleanMemory(int *arg)
{
    cout << "===============-Clean Memory-==============" << endl;

    cout << "Old value is: " << arg << endl;
    delete arg;
    arg = nullptr;
    cout << "Cleaned value: " << arg << endl;

    cout << "===============-Clean Memory-===============" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *pa = new int;
    *pa = 10;
    cout << *pa << endl;

    CleanMemory(pa);

    cout << "Must be clean value: " << pa << endl;

    if (pa != nullptr)
    {
        cout << endl << "Value is not cleaned." << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

В консоли получаю такой вывод:

```
10
===============-Clean Memory-==============
Old value is: 004B0568
Cleaned value: 00000000
===============-Clean Memory-===============
Must be clean value: 004B0568

Value is not cleaned.
```

То есть функция выполняется правильно и выводит, что указатель равен nullptr, но проверка вне ее показывает, что указатель равен 004B0568. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Вы нигде не изменяете значение указателя `pa` после инициализации, почему вы ожидаете, что оно станет `nullptr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой пример:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x)
{
    x = 1;
}

int main() 
{
    int y = 0;
    foo(y);
    std::cout << y;
}
```

Что выведет этот код, `1`?

`0`, потому что в С/С++ аргументы в функции передаются по значению (если не использовать ссылки), т.е. копируются при передаче в функцию. Все изменения производятся над копией, и не видны снаружи функции.

У вас происходит то же самое, только с указателем.

---

Решение: передавать указатель по ссылке: `void CleanMemory(int *&arg)`.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поменять сигнатуру функции на такую:

```
void CleanMemory(int *&arg)
{
    cout << "===============-Clean Memory-==============" << endl;

    cout << "Old value is: " << arg << endl;
    delete arg;
    arg = nullptr;
    cout << "Cleaned value: " << arg << endl;

    cout << "===============-Clean Memory-===============" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к совету передвать по ссылке - можно еще и адрес использовать:

```
void CleanMemory(int **arg)
{
    cout << "===============-Clean Memory-==============" << endl;

    cout << "Old value is: " << *arg << endl;
    delete *arg;
    *arg = nullptr;
    cout << "Cleaned value: " << *arg << endl;

    cout << "===============-Clean Memory-===============" << endl;
}

...

int *pa = new int;
*pa = 10;
cout << *pa << endl;

CleanMemory(&pa);
```